# Prevent unauthorized purchases from Microsoft Store using Microsoft account "2nd Factor Auth"

Tags: xbox, microsoft-store, microsoft

My Microsoft account has a credit card worth around 80 Euros.
My daughter knows the PIN of my Microsoft account. She is still too young for me to set up her own Microsoft account.

I saw by chance that it is possible to buy a DLC in the *Minecraft Marketplace* without using 2FA auth. I have configured 2FA on my Microsoft account and only I have access to the 2nd factor.

How can I make sure that any spending of credit requires a 2FA?

Comment: I wonder if there is an option somewhere in your Microsoft account settings to require 2FA for purchases. Haven't been able to find anything otherwise

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply change the PIN for your MS account?

Comment: I don't know how feasible this is for you but, for my son, I created a Microsoft account claiming he's 18. I then linked him as a family member and, if we use the same Xbox, he can use any games I own and have installed. I can also gift him games as and when necessary. It also means that, when he comes of age, his account is already set up, he can update his DOB, and already has a game library that doesn't require re-buying any games.

Comment: @Sybil DOB = Date of Birth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to Microsoft, the two-step verification is not enabled/used when buying stuff directly from your console.

While you can set up two-step verification (2FA) for your Microsoft account, it may not be used for every purchase made in the Microsoft Store or in-game marketplaces like Minecraft’s. This means that even if you have 2FA enabled, it might not prompt for the second factor of authentication for every transaction.

If your daughter knows the PIN of your Microsoft account, you might want to change it to something she doesn’t know. This can prevent unauthorized access to your account.

However, some platforms, like Xbox, allow you to set up a passkey that’s required for making purchases. This is different from your account PIN and could provide an extra layer of security.

Comment: Here’s how you can do it:

Press the Xbox button to open the guide.
Go to Profile & system > Settings > Account > Sign-in, security & PIN.
Select Create my PIN.
Enter a 6-digit PIN, and then re-enter the PIN to confirm.

This passkey will be required for making purchases, which can prevent unauthorized charges. Let me know if it works for you.

For additional help go here: https://support.xbox.com/en-US/help/family-online-safety/passkey-guest-key/create-and-manage-xbox-one-passkey